# Add extra div-class/wrap div class around existing div in Drupal

Tags: css, class, drupal

On my Drupal website I've got something like this:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-1">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-2">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-3">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-4">
...
```

Is there any way to get it like this

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-1 added-class">
```

or

```
<div class="wrapped-class">
   <div class="form-item form-type-textfield item-1">
</div>
```

So, to add a class to an item or wrap one around it. I played around with the `hook_preprocess`, but that didn't work out.

A `hook_form_alter` isn't the solution either, since you have to do it for each form... The div-class appears on multiple pages, so I would like to catch the statement with one code-snippet.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised Drupal hasn't 'farmed out' this functionality but if you look at the [`theme_form_element()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) you can see the classes are statically set.

The only way I can think to do what you want in code is to use a theme override for that function:

```
function mytheme_form_element($variables) {

}
```

In that function you'll need to place the entire code from the `theme_form_element` function (seems like overkill I know but I can't think of a better way), and add your new class to the `$attributes['class']` array:

```
$attributes['class'] = array('form-item', 'my-other-class');
```

Comment: If my theme is called `module`, I just need to do this `module_form_element($variable)`, right? Or do I need to replace another thing?

Comment: Ooo that's not a good choice for a theme name! So many functions in Drupal start with `module_` that you could easily run into namespace issue further down the line. But yes, `module_form_element` would be the correct function name. Remember to clear Drupal's caches once you've implemented the theme override :)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of the Drupal naming convention :) It was just the first word which I came up with :-) I'm working on a more solid solution right now. 'Cause Drupal won't let me change the attributes...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to put it, have a look at the template files for that block/region/page and create a template to override that. For example, if you want to add that div to every node, I would create a node.tpl.php inside my custom theme and add it there. As I say, it depends on where you want to put it.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but I would like to do it in code... Isn't there any function which pops into your mind? 'Cause mine already broke :)